# Using audio files as no input prompts in Google Actions

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to set up re-prompts in my Google Action, and I require them to be audio files.

This is my implementation:

```
    'use strict';

const { dialogflow } = require("actions-on-google");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  conv.noInputs = [`<speak> <audio src = "https://myurl.com/audio/myfile.mp3">My audio file</audio></speak>`];
  console.log("Logging the conversation object... ");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(conv));
  conv.ask("Hello! ");
});
exports.yourAction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

However, at the moment it will just read the raw string of this noInputs array when I do a "no input" in the dev console!

Answer (score 1):

Using this kind of static no-input handling is not suggested.

Better is to [create an Intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reprompts#dialogflow_2) that handles the `actions_intent_NO_INPUT` Event. You can then use the response section (or a response from your Fulfillment) to include SSML with the audio tag.